# How to convert a complex Python Dict into JSON serializable payload for an API?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So, I have the following DICT in python:

```
{'documentType': {'documentTypeId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'documentTypeName': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'documentTypeVersion': 1},
'tags': [{'boundingBoxCoOrdinates': {'x1': 440.66135,
    'y1': 894.0904,
    'x2': 468.74966,
    'y2': 917.39105},
   'digitalPdfTagDetails': {'startPage': 0,
    'endPage': 0,
    'startCharIndex': 0,
    'endCharIndex': 0},
   'editedDate': 'SOMEDATET12:47:36Z',
   'contains': True,
   'tagId': 0,
   'tagName': 'SOMETAG',
   'type': 'SOMETYPE',
   'color': '#SOMECOLOR',
   'extractedData': '',
   'editedData': '',
   'editedBy': 'SOMEPERSON'}],
'uploadedFileId': 'SOMEID',
'imageHeight': 55,
'imageWidth': 55,
'Engine': 'SOMEPROCESSINGENGINE',
'fileName': 'SOMEFILENAME.jpg'}
```

When I pass it for a POST api using Requests library in the JSON argument, I am greeted with

```
TypeError: Object of type 'float32' is not JSON serializable
```

I suspect, this is because of the values inside the 'boundingBoxCoOrdinates' which are numpy.float32 type. If I convert them to numpy.float64 using astype(numpy.float64), then it seems to be working fine.

How do I convert all such values in this DICT so as to JSON serializable error does not persist?

EDIT: There can be multiple such dictionaries inside 'tags' LIST

Comment: Do you need float32 type, can you convert it to simple float? If so, does it work?

Comment: I am actually getting this DICT from another datasource. I simply have to iterate through many such DICTS and for each DICT call a POST API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a custom encoder for all data types that don't fit in the standard range of data types.

Custom encoders are created by subclassing the `json.JSONEncoder` class:

```
import json
import numpy as np

class NumpyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
     def default(self, obj):
         if isinstance(obj, np.float32):
             return "...an appropriate representation of the item that the recipient understands..."
         # add more cases for NumPy data types as you need them

         # all other cases get default encoding
         return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


json_str = json.dumps(your_data_structure, cls=NumpyEncoder)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated into the requests documentation [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), you can use `json` parameter to let requests manage the encoding of the dict as this:

```py
url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
payload = {'some': 'data'}

r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

But, since you're getting that error, you can try to encode the dict yourself and send it via the `data` parameter like this:

```py
import json

url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
payload = {'some': 'data'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default argument in the json call to handle conversion of numpy arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
import json

d = {"floats": np.ones(10) / np.arange(1, 11)}

def handler(x):
    if isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        return [y.item() for y in x]
    else:
        return x

json_str = json.dumps(d, default=handler)
```